# Updating a collection across multiple classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have list of objects with around 500k items in it. Object class has around 100 (total) properties in it (nested or otherwise). All of the properties of this model are interlinked.

I am enriching/assigning values to these classes in various class called `Enricher` since each value assignment has it's own big logic.

Is is a good way to update a list item across multiple classes? Please note I have to store the intermediate values inside the enrichers.

I have class design like below

```
 class MyItem
    {
        public bool IsXyz { get; set; }
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        public Tuple<string, string> MyTuple { get; set; }
        public double Rate { get; set; }
        //Like these around 100 properties
    }

    class Enricher1
    {
        public void Enrich(MyItem myItem)
        {
            myItem.IsXyz = true;
        }
    }

    class Enricher2
    {
        public void Enrich(MyItem myItem)
        {
            myItem.Value = 3M;
        }
    }

    class Enricher3
    {
        public void Enrich(MyItem myItem)
        {
            myItem.MyTuple = Tuple.Create("Test", "Test");
        }
    }

    class Enricher4
    {
        public void Enrich(MyItem myItem)
        {
            myItem.Rate = 300;
        }
    }
```

Comment: just because they are all interlinked doesn't mean you can group them better in other sub classes. Also you're question is unclear what are  your trying to do?

Comment: Believe me, your objects probably do not need to be that size with that many properties! Have you thought about dividing your class' properties up into other classes, then having those objects as the property type? Such as `class RidiculousPropsClass { int mileage, int litresFuel, int ... }` to `class RidiculousPropsClass { CarProperties properties } ... class CarProperties { int mileage, int litresFuel, int ... }`

Comment: You can take a look at Observer design pattern, since it solve the problem of updating multiple objects when a specified object is updated. Your question is a little bit confusing.

Comment: Decorator also came to mind.  But the question appears to be unanswerable without some idea of what you're trying to accomplish here.  Overall, it doesn't look like a design that is maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question is not about how many prop is good in class. My query is is it a good practice to update/enrich an object properties in multiple classes?

Comment: There's no way to know without knowing more about what the purpose of your design is.

Comment: (1) You say "Object **class** has around 100 (total) properties in it (nested or otherwise). All of the properties of this **model** are interlinked." What is the difference between "class" and "model", if any? (2) How are they interlinked? Are really **all** properties interlinked? That seems unusual. The nature of the inter-dependencies would probably influence the way you update a property. (3) Why do you have a subclass to set a property and not just a setter function? Do you need an object to keep state between different calls? Your example certainly doesn't need this complication.

Comment: Ah, I just realized that you give an answer to (3): you need to store intermediate values. Then it may make sense.